# python advance for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am an old dog who used BASIC > 30 years ago.  I have run into this scenario in using for loops in python before, but I picked this illustration for my concern about loops:

I would like to parse a long string which includes words in double quotes separated by commas.  I can ignore double quotes, but I want the loop to advance here.  I don't feel like this is very elegant.  I am carrying unnecessary looping baggage.  Should I do away with the loop altogether, in which case, is slicing the preferred method, and is there a general rule to apply to the question of using loops or not?

```
"""
data is the str-type variable
line, despite the name, seems to pull out just one character at a time
(which is not relevant except to confirm my naïveté in python)
"""

for line in data:
    if line.endswith('"'):
        x = True  # doing nothing but advancing the for loop
    elif line.endswith(','):
        #  do something at a comma
    else:
        #  continue the parsing
```

**Edit** Example string:

```
"All","the","world","'s","a","stage","And","all","the","men","and","women","merely","players"
```

Comment: You can use `continue` to advance a loop

Comment: Looping over a string pulls out one character at a time because that is the defined behavior. I don't know how else to put it. You might try reading something like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely rename `line`. That's very misleading/confusing for starters.

Comment: Thank you, @idjaw; sample input added.  I did not know about the continue command @cricket_007, thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? It could be that there is a better way to parse your data.

Comment: Thanks, Jared, yes, this is coming straight from a text file of these concatenated words in double quotes separated by strings.  with open('shakes.txt' , 'r') and reading it in without the punctuation would be a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to parse a long string which includes words in double quotes separated by commas

Let `data` be

```
data = '''"this","is","a","test"'''
```

Then you can `split()` on commas

```
for quote in data.split(','):
```

> I can ignore double quotes

Yes, you can `strip()` the quotes

```
    word = quote.strip('"')
```

Then print

```
    print(word)
```

---

All together

```
data = '''"this","is","a","test"'''

for quote in data.split(','):
    word = quote.strip('"')
    print(word)
```

Outputs

```
this
is
a
test
```

Answer (score 3):

For your general questions about loops, if you want to parse the string line by line, you can do either:

```
for line in data.split('\n'):
    …
```

or

```
for line in data.splitlines():
    …
```

> … *long string which includes words in double quotes separated by commas. I can ignore double quotes, but I want the loop to advance here* …

But after reading your question several times, you never said you actually want to iterate over lines. Instead, you might want to split your strings at the comma:

```
for element in data.split(','):
    …
```

and then, if you want to remove the quotes, you can strip them out:

```
    element.strip('"\'')
```

edit:

here's a go with your example, to extract each word:

```
>>> s = '''"All","the","world","'s","a","stage","And","all","the","men","and","women","merely","players"'''
>>> 
>>> for element in s.split(','):
...     element = element.strip('"')
...     print(element)
... 
All
the
world
's
a
stage
And
all
the
men
and
women
merely
players
```

HTH

Comment: Where does it say in the question there are new lines?

Comment: well, in his code: `for line in data` this is why in doubt, I answered to both cases ☺

Comment: I see. I was reading too far into *line, despite the name, seems to pull out just one character at a time*

Answer (score 1):

Since `data` is `str` the for loop will advance one character at a time. If you want to split the `str` to lines separated by newline character you can do so by [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method that returns a list of lines:

```
for line in data.split('\n'):
    # do something with line
```

Comment: you can also use `data.splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data` is a string containing something like

```
"one", "two", "tree", ...
```

you might split your line into "one", "two" and "tree" chunks and get rid of quotes like this:

```
for element in [x[1:-1] for x in data.split(",")]:
    print element
```

This makes use of so called [`list comprehensions`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: You're missing a `]`. Also, there are no spaces in the sample input.